Scaling million rules : create generic rules and pass variables on both sides of a condition as facts
Working to determine if drools is appropriate for my use case that I plan to migrate from legacy architecture.

As you've already guessed, using an external function in rule evaluation would be more convenient while defining the rules, but not as fast as executing a compiled rule.
In order for your rules evaluation to be efficient, you need all the rules compiled inside a RETE network. To do that, you need to have those rules at a certain point, either by writing them explicitly or building those programmatically.
How you generate those rules is up to you, but if you know most of the rules are identical and differ only by static parameters you could use either decision tables and let Drools generate your rules from it or there's a a specific section dedicated to DSLs on the manual or else you could directly the executable model API or the Rule Unit DSL API

Thank you Luca. Sorry I think it was a two fold question instead of just one. I believe your response on keeping everything within RETE network is because I intend to lucene search for complex searches and not just limit to regex, I see your point but lucene provides me with better pattern matching as all my records have complex patterns to search/match for.
Two is to pass parameters dynamically for both sides of equality in LHS. I believe that is possible from your response but u want to compile ahead of time as part of rule compilation.
